# Create 2 or more tables for one class in ORMLite

Tags: android, database, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite on Android and have the following question:
Is it possible to create many tables based on a single Java class?

The tables should only differ in their names, and the access to them should be by name.

For example if I have a class:

```
public class Order{
    @DatabaseField
    public string Name;

    @DatabaseField
    public string Amount;
}
```

I have been throught the question [Create multiple tables for one class in ORMLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038730/create-multiple-tables-for-one-class-in-ormlite) but my case modules are not Dynamic

I cannot have inheritance for some reasons like as mention by @grey.

```
@DatabaseTable
public class FooOrder extends Order {
    // fields will be gotten from Order
}

@DatabaseTable
public class BarOrder extends Order {
    // fields will be gotten from Order
}
```

Please someone help me in having 2 or more saperate tables which are created using same class.Can this be achived using `DataBasetableConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the some question with you.And I solve it.
http://blog.csdn.net/lonelyroamer/article/details/26299355

Hope is help for you.